# NHibernate could not compile the mapping

Tags: c#, xml, database, visual-studio, nhibernate

I don't know where is error.

I use NHibernate C# and append Assembly to Configuration.
Problem a **NHibernateException: Could not compile the mapping Note.hbm.xml**

```
public static class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static Configuration _cfg;
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory {
        get {
            if (_sessionFactory == null) {
                _cfg = new Configuration();
                _cfg.Configure();

                _cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(User).Assembly);
                _cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Changelog).Assembly);
                _cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Note).Assembly);


                _sessionFactory = _cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            }

            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }


    public static ISession OpenSession() {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    public static void DatabaseSchemaLoader() {
        ISession session = OpenSession();
        new SchemaExport(_cfg).Create(true, true);
        session.Close();
    }
}
```

My Note class is shared.data.content

```
namespace CRMSystem.shared.data.content
{
    public class Note
    {    
        public virtual int id { get; set; }
        public virtual string title{ get; set;}
        public virtual string text { get; set; }
        public virtual int priority { get; set; }
        public virtual long createdTime { get; set; }
        public virtual long lastEditTime { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

Note.hbm.xml (set build action: embedded resource, copy to output: copy always)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="CRMSystem"
                   namespace="CRMSystem.shared.data.content">

  <class name="Note" table="`Note`" lazy="false">


    <id name="id" column="`id`" type="int">
      <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="title" column="`title`" type="String"/>
    <property name="text" column="`text`" type="String" />
    <property name="priority" column="`priority`" type="int" />
    <property name="createdTime" column="`createdTime`" type="long" />
    <property name="lastEditTime" column="`lastEditTime`" type="long" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

Thanks for your answer.

I have tried today in many ways and found to that it works:

```
_cfg.Configure();
_cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(User).Assembly);
//_cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Changelog).Assembly);
//_cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Note).Assembly);
```

When I adds: (any class)

```
_cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Changelog).Assembly);
```

Every I get an error: Could not compile Note.hbm.xml
I can save to database every class (User, Changelog, Note).
I can't explain.

Has anyone ever have such situations ?

Full exception:

```
    NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: CRMSystem.shared.data.mapping.Note.hbm.xml ---> NHibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping CRMSystem.shared.data.content.Note
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Mappings.AddClass(PersistentClass persistentClass)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.RootClassBinder.Bind(HbmClass classSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddRootClasses(HbmClass rootClass, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.AddEntitiesMappings(HbmMapping mappingSchema, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.Bind(HbmMapping mappingSchema)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName)
   --- Koniec śladu stosu wyjątków wewnętrznych ---
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue()
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocumentThroughQueue(NamedXmlDocument document)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddXmlReader(XmlReader hbmReader, String name)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String path, Assembly assembly)
   w NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly assembly)
```

When I nothing add , i get exception : no persister

Comment: maybe remove single coute in column attribute Note.hbm.xml

Comment: Firstly - Move YOUR answer into your question. Delete that answer. Secondly could you also append the full stack of inner Exception? As I did? There will be clear answer

Comment: Could you show the **full** exception? Exactly after your cite *Could not compile Note.hbm.xml*  - exactly that next line is saying clearly what is the problem. Observe my own answer and you will see such extract I created for you...

Comment: I'm sorry. I had problem with print stack trace.

Comment: Not a problem .. I extended the answer (and locally tested to get the same error)  . Simply - one of your hbm.xml files contains `<class name="Note"`... search for it and you have a culprit

Answer (score 1):

EXTEND

Based on the latest update, we can see, that NHiberante is blaming at:

> ... Duplicate class/entity mapping CRMSystem.shared.data.content.Note ...

And that means, that in our case, some other file could contain the NOTE mapping, e.g. in user.hbm.xml there could be some forgotten mapping

```
<class name="Note" ...
```

ORIGINAL part

The code is ok **as is**. I tried locally with your **`Note`** class and **`Note.hbm.xml`**. Working as expected.

The issue seems to be some misspelling which I can hardly reproduce *(e.g. different assembly name)*. Or, despite of the blame on the Note.hbm.xml ... it also could be some other mapping

```
// there could be also some issue
_cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(User).Assembly);
_cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Changelog).Assembly);
```

Anyhow, try to observe the INNER exception. There will be clear issue description. E.g. for this mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               // instead of this
               // assembly="CRMSystem"
               // we have this
               assembly="WrongAssembly"
               namespace="CRMSystem.shared.data.content">
```

We would receive full exception:

> NHibernate.MappingException: **Could not compile the mapping document**: ...**Note.hbm.xml** ---> NHibernate.MappingException: persistent class
>   **CRMSystem.shared.data.content.Note, WrongAssembly** not found ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WrongAssembly' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

Note: **embedded resource** property is must, **do not copy** is suggested. This file will be part of dll, it does not have to be copied as a file.

Comment: Any progress? have you find the ghost `<class name="Note"` definition?